# save the json response from geocoding in a json file with libcurl in c

Tags: c, json, libcurl

i'm using geocoding to retrieve the latitude and longitude of an address by using libcurl functions. it works fine, and the program prints me the json response in the ubuntu terminal. I just don't know how use the WRITEFUNCTION option in libcurl to save the response from the google server in a json file. it works with a normal text file with the write_data function, I don't know how to have the data in a json file.

If anyone knows, thanks!

Gioia

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is follow the official [url2file.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/url2file.html) example. Take care to:

- change the output file name if you wish (see `pagefilename`). Optional: use the `.json` extension - it is just a way to *indicate* that this file contains JSON
- use `"w"` as open mode instead of `"wb"` (i.e `fopen(pagefilename, "w");`)

Notes:

- a JSON file is no more than a text file with UTF-8 encoding by default,
- libcurl can alternatively be combined with a JSON library so as to manipulate a JSON object post-transfer. Here's an example with [json-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c) that features progressive JSON parsing: https://github.com/deltheil/json-url

Comment: thank you so much, I just wanna know if i can create a json object in the code, like with json_object * jobj = json_object_new_object(); and then put the content of the response directly in that. is it the same thing of manipulating a file?

Comment: You can freely combine libcurl with c-json that way. But there is even better: you can take benefit of json-c progressive parsing capability, so that you have a ready-to-use JSON object post-transfer. I've edited the answer with a link to a sample code.

Comment: Thank you again for the kindness. I was wondering where that functions were, since I saw the "json_object_to_json_string" function.